# I can't show an element after I hide it

Tags: javascript, jquery

So after I hide first element( the main menu ) I show another menu with inputs and two buttons ( Play and Return ). When I click return I want to go back to the main menu( first element ) but show() and hide() doesn't work anymore and I can't figure out why. I want to make this app in Electron, but I tried on web browser too, is the same. If you can help me I will be very thankful !

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

$('#AIbtn, #PVPbtn').click(function() {
 if( this.id == 'AIbtn') {
  show_ai_menu();
 }
 else if( this.id == 'PVPbtn') {
  show_pvp_menu();

 }
 else if( this.id == 'returnBTN') {
  show_init_menu();
 }
});

function show_ai_menu() {
 $(".removeContent").hide();
 $(".afterClick").show(function() {
  $(this).append("<p class='infoText'>Please, enter your name !</p>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classFrm' <form><input class='formGame' type='text' name='pnAI' value='Player 1'></input></form></div>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton Playbtn' id='playPVA'>Play !</div>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton AIbtn' id='returnBTN'>Return  <i class='fas fa-undo-alt'></i></div>");
 });
}
function show_pvp_menu() {
 $(".removeContent").hide();
 $(".afterClick").show(function() {
  $(this).append("<p class='infoText'>Please, enter your name !</p>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classFrm'><form><input class='formGame' type='text' name='pnPVP1' value='Player 1'></input></div>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classFrm'><input class='formGame' type='text' name='pnPVP2' value='Player 2'></input></form></div>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton Playbtn' id='playPVP'>Play !</div>");
  $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton AIbtn' id='returnBTN'>Return  <i class='fas fa-undo-alt'></i></div>");
 });
}
function show_init_menu() {
 $(".afterClick").hide();
 $(".removeContent").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the below function, the third clause is unreachable (you're only attaching click events to `AIbtn` and `PVPbtn`, so `this.id` can never be `returnBTN`.)

```
$('#AIbtn, #PVPbtn').click(function() {
  if (this.id == 'AIbtn') {
    show_ai_menu();
  } else if (this.id == 'PVPbtn') {
    show_pvp_menu();  
  } else if (this.id == 'returnBTN') {
    show_init_menu();
  }
});
```

This can't be fixed by just adding that ID to the selector list, though, because the `returnBTN` element doesn't exist yet at the time that you're assigning these click events (since you only append it to the DOM later as part of one of the `show_foo_menu()` functions.

You could use a [delegated event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) instead, attaching it to a parent element which is always present:

```js
$('#parent').on("click", "#AIbtn, #PVPbtn, #returnBTN", function() {
  if (this.id == 'AIbtn') {
    show_ai_menu();
  } else if (this.id == 'PVPbtn') {
    show_pvp_menu();
  } else if (this.id == 'returnBTN') {
    show_init_menu();
  }
});

function show_ai_menu() {
  $(".removeContent").hide();
  $(".afterClick").show(function() {
    $(this).empty(); // don't duplicate the content
    $(this).append("<p class='infoText'>Please, enter your name !</p>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classFrm' <form><input class='formGame' type='text' name='pnAI' value='Player 1'></input></form></div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton Playbtn' id='playPVA'>Play !</div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton AIbtn' id='returnBTN'>Return  <i class='fas fa-undo-alt'></i></div>");
  });
}

function show_pvp_menu() {
  $(".removeContent").hide();
  $(".afterClick").show(function() {
    $(this).empty(); // don't duplicate the content  
    $(this).append("<p class='infoText'>Please, enter your name !</p>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classFrm'><form><input class='formGame' type='text' name='pnPVP1' value='Player 1'></input></div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classFrm'><input class='formGame' type='text' name='pnPVP2' value='Player 2'></input></form></div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton Playbtn' id='playPVP'>Play !</div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='classBtns'><button type='button' class='gameButton AIbtn' id='returnBTN'>Return  <i class='fas fa-undo-alt'></i></div>");
  });
}

function show_init_menu() {
  $(".afterClick").hide();
  $(".removeContent").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="removeContent">
    <button id="AIbtn">AIbtn</button>
    <button id="PVPbtn">PVPbtn</button>
  </div>

  <div class="afterClick"></div>
</div>
```

...but in this case it seems like it might be simpler to not modify the DOM during the show/hide phase: instead of using `append()` to change the contents of `.afterClick`, put those contents in the DOM in the first place, in separate elements, and start out with them hidden.

#### Side note

The way you're currently using `.show()` *is* allowed by jQuery -- the method signature `.show( [duration ] [, complete ] )` means that both duration and the "complete" function are optional, so omitting duration is allowed.  (The way you're currently doing it is a little bit confusing, though; personally I'd either include a duration or use the more explicit `{complete: function(){...}}` signature.)

However, the effect of waiting until `show` completes before inserting the element's contents into the DOM is that you lose the animation on the first run (because the first time you call it, the element is empty when you try to show it.)  If you do still need to insert this content into the DOM on the fly, rather than having it be in place but hidden on page load, it would probably be better to set the content before showing the element rather than after:

```
$('.afterClick').empty().append("your HTML here").show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Like Ashay said, show does not have a signature that match your usage.
See the doc : http://api.jquery.com/show/
If you want to execute your code when the animation is complete, you can

`$(...).show({complete: function myCompleteCallback() {...} })`

or

`$(...).show(400 /* duration*/,function myCompleteCallback() {...})`

And if you want to execute your code synchronously (not to wait the complete of the show), see again Ashay's answer (put your code after the call to show).